# How can I simplify the code in my _uniq function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, uniq

I have been given a problem in which I am supposed to build the _.uniq function from the underscore library.  I have been able to get it to pass all of the tests but I know I have done it in a very convoluted way and I think there's something fundamental I am missing about how the function works along with the provided iterator function.  When I spoke with a TA from the program I'm attending he said while my thought process would work there is an easier way to do it.  The only way I can think of though is to store the results of the iterator in a separate array, sort out the unique elements in an object, then push those elements to another array and return that array.  Can anyone help me simplify my code?

```js
_.uniq = function(array, isSorted, iterator) {
    var uniqueArray = [];
    var storeObj = {};
    var iteratorArray = [];

    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
      if (iterator) {
        iteratorArray.push(iterator(item));
      } else {
        iteratorArray.push(_.identity(item));
      }
    });

    _.each(iteratorArray, function(item, index) {
      if (storeObj[item] === undefined) {
        storeObj[item] = array[index];
      }
    });

    for(var key in storeObj) {
      uniqueArray.push(storeObj[key]);
    }

    return uniqueArray;
  };
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the source code](https://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-62)?

Comment: I did but it didn't really help my understanding of the problem.